# Rails validates_presence_of with multiple fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have multiple fields that should be validated with presence option.
I am trying to use `validates_presence_of` instead of `validates`.

**Here is my code**

```
validates_presence_of : first_name, last_name, birthday, sex,home, message: "This field shouldn't be blank"
```

But I want to show field name in the message. How can I show field name in message?

Comment: You are using `message` with *capital M*. Is it a typo?

Comment: sorry , Pavan - its kinda typo. it should be 'm', Anyway.

Answer (score 12):

If you remove the message hash, and just use

```
validates_presence_of :first_name, :last_name, :birthday, :sex, :home
```

This will display a message containing all the field names that are blank when you are saving your object.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried to used but it doesn't work. It only displays "can't be blank" as error message , without field name. Unfortunately , it doesn't work.

Comment: Strange, it works for me :/ . Could you provide the whole Customer model and rails version you are using

Comment: Would you like to provide me the error messages you've got when field is empty?

Comment: `validates_presence_of :name, :phone_no, :email` #raises
`ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Name can't be blank, Phone no can't be blank, Email can't be blank`

Comment: better validate separately for better error messages such as:
```validates :first_name, presence: true```